# How are fragment activity layouts affected by main activity layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

After having been introduced to Android development and creating a few basic applications, I have begun splitting activities into fragments for reusability. However one thing that I'm still slightly confused about is how the layout of the main activity(which holds the fragments), is affected by the layouts defined for fragment activities and vice versa.

While I believe that the layouts would affect each other based on definitions of height and width for each fragment, the number of fragments in an activity, etc. However Im not sure if there are other rules I am unaware of and I want to know if the layouts specified for the fragments directly affect the way the way the layout of the main activity displays.

For example, the main activity has a RelativeLayout and contains two fragments which have LinearLayout defined in their own separate layout xml files. Do the LinearLayouts affect the way in which the RelativeLayout would normally display and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments are basically similar to other view like RelativeLayout or LinearLayout in some ways. For Example they can also have width and height; Fragments can expand on the basis of size of its children. Rest is up on you, how you design layouts (fragments). Fragment is also similar to Activity in a sense that it has its own xml layout and corresponding java class. Primarily, we use fragments in two ways:

i) One or more fragments capturing separate parts (space) of activity at a time.

ii) A particular fragment in activity which is replaced (add,remove,replace) by many other fragments programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use fragments statically in the layout files of your activities and dynamically by adding them in containers which you also define in the layout files of your activities.

The fragment view, will be inflated and be displayed in its container. It all depends on how you define your container. If you make it so it match the width of its parent, the layout of the fragment can have a width as much as the parent of the container. It is like putting views into that container.